# How can I use django-userena login and logout forms in every page with djangocms?

Tags: django, django-cms, django-userena

I have a site running with djangocms and I need the login and logout capabilities of django-userena, it's easy for me to use this because every user will have a profile page too. The design for the menu in every page states that a simple login form has to be in the top right corner of the menu. I have already done that, but I need the django-userena login to work with it. How can I do it?

I have tried to add the form in my base.html. Also tried with a middleware.py like this

```
    class LoginFormMiddleware(object):
        def process_request(self, request):
        from userena.forms import AuthenticationForm
        if request.method == 'POST' and request.POST.has_key('base-account') and request.POST['base-account'] == 'Login':
        form = AuthenticationForm(data=request.POST, prefix="login")
        if form.is_valid():
            from django.contrib.auth import login
            login(request, form.get_user())
        request.method = 'GET'
    else:
        form = AuthenticationForm(request, prefix="login")
    request.login_form = form

class LogoutFormMiddleware(object):
def process_request(self, request):
    if request.method == 'POST' and request.POST.has_key('base-account') and request.POST['base-account'] == 'Logout':
        from userena.views import signout
        signout(request)
        request.method = 'GET'
```

base.html

```
<form class="navbar-form navbar-right login-strip" action="" method="post">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        <p id="login">
                            {{ request.login_form.non_field_errors }}
                            {% for field in request.login_form %}
                                {{ field.errors }}
                                {{ field.label_tag}}: {{ field }}
                            {% endfor %}
                            <input type="submit" name="base-account" value="Login" />
                        </p>
                    </form>
                    {% else %}
                    <form class="navbar-form navbar-right login-strip" action="" method="post">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        <p id="logout">Logged in as <b>{{ request.user.username }}</b>.
                            <input type="submit" name="base-account" value="Logout" />
                        </p>
                    </form>
                    {% endif %}
```

This gives me this error 
'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'get'

Answer (score 0):

I have tried a lot of thighs in this.
Now I'm not using any side django-authetication I just put some code in my menu.html this way I can login and log out as need.
My problem was the normal account has no way to logout.

My work around is that:

menu.html

```html
{% load i18n menu_tags cache %}

{% for child in children %}
 <li class="{% if child.ancestor %}ancestor{% endif %}
  {% if child.selected %} active{% endif %}
  {% if child.children %} dropdown{% endif %}">
  {% if child.children %}
   <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
    {{ child.get_menu_title }} <span class="caret"></span>
   </a>
   <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    {% show_menu from_level to_level extra_inactive extra_active template "" "" child %}
   </ul>
  {% else %}
   <a href="{{ child.get_absolute_url }}"><span>{{ child.get_menu_title }}</span></a>
  {% endif %}
  </li>
  {% if class and forloop.last and not forloop.parentloop %}{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
  <li class="User" style="position: absolute; right: 0;">
   <a >
    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                    <form method="post" action= "accounts/logout/?next={{ request.path }}">
      {% csrf_token %}
      <button type="submit" class="cms-btn cms-btn-action"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> {{ request.user.username }}</button>
     </form>
    {% else %}
                    <form action="{% url 'pages-root' %}{% if request.path != logout_url %}?next={{ request.path }}&amp;{{ cms_edit_on }}&amp;cms-toolbar-login=1{% endif %}"
                        class="cms-toolbar-item cms-form-login" method="post">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        <label{% if request.toolbar.login_form.username.errors or request.toolbar.login_form.non_field_errors or cms_toolbar_login_error %} class="cms-error"{% endif %}>
                            <span>{% trans request.toolbar.login_form.username.label %}</span>
                            {{ request.toolbar.login_form.username }}
                        </label>
                        <label{% if request.toolbar.login_form.password.errors or request.toolbar.login_form.non_field_errors or cms_toolbar_login_error %} class="cms-error"{% endif %}>
                            <span>{% trans request.toolbar.login_form.password.label %}</span>
                            {{ request.toolbar.login_form.password }}
                        </label>
                        <label>
                            <input class="cms-btn cms-btn-action" type="submit" value="{% trans 'Login' %}">
                        </label>
                    </form>
    {% endif %}
   </a>
  </li>
```

urls.py added this:

url(r'^accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),

Answer (score 0):

I end up with this code, more mobile friend.

```
<li class="User" style="position: absolute; right: 0;">
        <a >
            {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                <form method="post" action= "accounts/logout/?next={{ request.path }}">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <p id="logout"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> <b>{{ request.user.username }}</b>
                    <button type="submit" class="cms-btn cms-btn-action"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-off"></span> {% trans "Logout" %}</button>
                </form>
            {% else %}
                <form method="post" action="{{request.path}}?edit">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> {% trans "Login" %}</button>
                </form>
            {% endif %}
        </a>
    </li>
```